# How to Create a Footertemplate for KoGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal, kogrid

How can I create footer Template for a koGrid to display sum of a column?

```
 gridOptions : {
        displaySelectionCheckbox: false,
        data: items,
       // selectedItems: self.selectedItems,
        multiSelect: false,

        enableColumnResize: true,

        columnDefs: [
                      { field: 'fun_id', displayName: 'fun_id', visible: false },
                      { field: 'test', displayName: 'Test' },
                      { field: 'details', displayName: 'Details'},
                      { field: 'qty', displayName: 'Qty' },
                      { field: 'price', displayName: 'Price' },
                      { field: 'discount', displayName: 'Discount' },
                      { field: 'empno', displayName: 'EmpNo' },
                      { field: 'promo', displayName: 'Promo' },
                      { field: 'Delete', cellTemplate: myCellTemplate, width: 60 },
        ]
    }
```

[image]

Here I want to print the sum of 'price' field as Total in Footer.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [Kendo aggregation demo](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.aggregates) all you need to do is define an aggregate property